# Gitlab CI/CD shell executor reading files/running python scripts

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been recently introduced to Gitlab CI/CD and currently learning different ways on how to optimize our development.

We are working on various Embedded Software projects (programming various MCU's).

Everytime we are ready to perform a release, we would like to run an automated hardware level testing (Toggling GPIO pins, sending some serial commands to the device and etc). For that we have our own Python tool and we can run it using command line.

In order to automate this process, I have setup a simple Raspberry PI 4 (Installed gitlab-runner and I have setup the shell executor for my gitlab project). The runner config:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Raspberry PI TestTool runner"
  url = "https://xxx-gitlab=xxxxxxx.lt/"
  id = 12
  token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-01-02T07:51:55Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "bash"
```

And my pipeline is as following:

```
# List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
stages:
  - test

test-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"
    - ls -l
    - cd ~
    - ls -l
    - cat Desktop/test.txt
```

As you can see from the pipeline above, all I am trying to do currently is to read the text inside the `test.txt` document.

I can easily do that on the Raspberry PI itself:

```
lukas@raspberrypi:/etc $ cd ~
lukas@raspberrypi:~ $ cat Desktop/test.txt
hello123
```

but when trying to run a job, it fails:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.7.0 (102c81ba)
  on Raspberry PI TestTool runner htiDWYJ2, system ID: s_0ae6b2582ae5
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on raspberrypi...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/htiDWYJ2/0/embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test/.git/
Checking out 7f12264a as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ echo "This job tests something"
This job tests something
$ ls -l
total 120
drwxr-xr-x 8 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  4096 Jan  2 08:13 build
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   235 Jan  2 08:13 CMakeLists.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  4096 Jan  2 08:22 main
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  2921 Jan  2 08:13 Readme.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     2 Jan  2 08:13 release_notes.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 48870 Jan  2 08:13 sdkconfig
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     0 Jan  2 08:13 sdkconfig.ci
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 48870 Jan  2 08:13 sdkconfig.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  1325 Jan  2 08:13 working_ci_scripts.txt
$ cd ~
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 4096 Jan  2 08:13 builds
$ cat Desktop/test.txt
cat: Desktop/test.txt: No such file or directory
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Perhaps I am completely misunderstanding how the `shell` executor works? Can I not access all files on the gitlab-runner (Raspberry PI 4) via CI/CD pipeline? In fact, this runner does not even need to clone the Gitlab repository since it will not need to build anything. It will simply need to execute some scripts and read some files that are located on the Raspberry PI 4.

If what I am trying to do is not possible using `shell` executor, what would the alternative method that would allow reading files/ executing python scripts on the gitlab-runner via CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: The user accounts `lukas` and `gitlab-runner` will have different home directories (`~`). Try using an absolute path instead and make sure the gitlab-runner user has access to read it.

Comment: You are right. I have tried to ```cd``` into user directory using CI/CD pipeline using ```cd /home/lukas``` but gitlab-runner did not have permissions to do that as I got the following error:  ```bash: line 153: cd: lukas: Permission denied``` I think I understand now. On my Raspberry PI there are 2 users:
```lukas``` and ```gitlab-runner```

I need to give ```gitlab-runner``` access to ```lukas``` user. I am trying to think of what would be the most appropriate method to do that.

Comment: You could consider just moving the files into the `/home/gitlab-runner` user directory or perhaps some other common directory outside of `/home/` altogether. For example, you may create a directory like `/opt/resources` and move the file there. Then make sure the directory `/opt/resources` is allowed to be accessed by both users (as a hint, the `chmod` command can be used to change file/directory permissions -- alternatively, your Rapberry Pi may have a desktop UI that allows you to do this graphically)

Comment: That makes sense. I have moved my file to ```tmp``` and now the ```gitlab-user``` can access the files there easily

Answer (score 0):

The gitlab-runner is not the same user than lukas.

lukas ~/ is different from gitlab-runner ~/

You can try to use pwd command to localize yourself and find your file in the filesystem.

Something like to go to
`/user/lukas/Desktop/test.txt`

should work.

Comment: I sort of understand what you mean but it is still not fully clear to me how can I localize myself and access ```lukas``` user files when running pipeline using shell executor. I dont think the Gitlab runner knows anything about user ```lukas```

Comment: If both are on the same machine, you could 'cd' in a script, but the best practice is to move the files to a centralized location and access via both users in the same way.